# Update an array where an object property has a specific value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I am trying to update an array where an object property has a specific value.

**The Details:**

I have a simple method (`setMissingFields(model)`) that takes `model` as parameter. In the method I am looping over the object (`model`), and would like to update an array (`missingArray[]`) when the property is set to `mandatory: true`.

Below is the "clean" code I have (I have tried various nested loops using `if (typeof (value) === 'object')`):

```
  model = {
    name: { value: '', mandatory: false },
    initials: { value: '', mandatory: false },
    physicalAddress: {
      addressPostalCode: { value: '', mandatory: true },
    },
    postalAddress: {
      address1: { value: '', mandatory: true },
    },
  };

  setMissingFields(model) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(model)) {

      if (value === '') {
        this.missingArray.push({ FieldName: key, ExpectedValue: ''});
      }
      else if (typeof (value) === 'object') {
        this.setMissingFields(value);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the expected output you want(missingArray) from the given json data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below looping method to get the desired output.
In every loop iteration it is checking if mandatory field exist or not in that object if it does then what is the value of that field and if value is true then I am also validating what does value field contains.

If it satisfy all the condition I am adding that field in new array.

If it does not then I am recursively invoking the same method with the current object.

```js
var resultset = [];
var model = {
    name: { value: '', mandatory: true },
    initials: { value: '', mandatory: false },
    physicalAddress: {
      addressPostalCode: { value: '', mandatory: true },
    },
    postalAddress: {
      address1: { value: '', mandatory: false },
    },
};

function filterkey(data) {
  if (data){
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
      var currentValue = value;
      if (value.hasOwnProperty("mandatory") 
        && value["mandatory"]===true && !value["value"]){
        console.log(key,value);
        resultset.push({fieldName:key,expectedValue:''})
      } else {
        filterkey(currentValue);
      }
    }
  }
}

filterkey(model);
console.log(resultset);
```